# percentage of rows containing x in R

Tags: r

Creating segmented proportion tables in R is pretty straightforward
    `data.frame(prop.table(table(df$x, df$y),2))`

...but now I have a column structure like this

```
         x                         y 
1        BMW, Mercedes, Toyota     M 
2        Toyota                    M 
3        GM, Ford                  M 
4        BMW                       M
5        Ford, Mercedes            F 
6        Toyota                    F
7        BMW, GM                   F
8        Toyota                    F
```

How do I create a proportion table (still segmented by y) that captures the percentage of rows *containing* each of the car manufacturers, knowing of course that the sum will be more than 1?

Comment: Please include sample code so someone could run your code

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this may be to break x up by car and put it in long format and then use `summarize()` from the dplyr package.

Make the data frame:

```
x <- c("BMW, Mercedes, Toyota", "Toyota", "GM, Ford", "BMW", "Ford, Mercedes", "Toyota", "BMW, GM", "Toyota")
y <- c(rep("M", 4), rep("F", 4))
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

Separate the list of cars in each entry of x, make each entry its own row (with `gather` and then `na.omit` to drop redundant missing entries), then reformat to wide (with `spread`), filling in 1 and 0 for each row indicating whether that car was mentioned. Then get the mean of each of the car columns within levels of y to get the proportion mentioning each car, separating by levels of y.

```
df %>% 
  separate(x, into=paste("car", 1:3), fill = "right") %>% 
  gather("key", "car", -y) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(temp = 1:nrow(.), hit=1) %>% 
  spread(car, hit, fill = 0, sep = "_") %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(starts_with("car_")), mean)

# A tibble: 2 × 6
       y   car_BMW  car_Ford    car_GM car_Mercedes car_Toyota
  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>
1      F 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667    0.1666667  0.3333333
2      M 0.2857143 0.1428571 0.1428571    0.1428571  0.2857143
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `data.table` and `lapply`:

```
library( magrittr )
library( data.table )
setDT( dt )
```

Make a list of the car makes represented

```
makes <- dt[['x']] %>%
    paste( collapse = ", " ) %>%
    strsplit( ", " ) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    unique()

> makes
[1] "BMW"      "Mercedes" "Toyota"   "GM"       "Ford"
```

Then use that to calculate the percentages (here keeping the original data intact).

```
dt[ , ( makes ) := 
        lapply( makes, grepl, x = x ) %>% 
        lapply( function( x ) { sum(x) / length(x) } ), 
    by = y ]
```

So we're creating new columns for each make, then filling those with the `sum/length` of occurrences of each model (ie: the percentage). Which gives:

```
> dt
                       x y  BMW Mercedes Toyota   GM Ford
1: BMW, Mercedes, Toyota M 0.50     0.25    0.5 0.25 0.25
2:                Toyota M 0.50     0.25    0.5 0.25 0.25
3:              GM, Ford M 0.50     0.25    0.5 0.25 0.25
4:                   BMW M 0.50     0.25    0.5 0.25 0.25
5:        Ford, Mercedes F 0.25     0.25    0.5 0.25 0.25
6:                Toyota F 0.25     0.25    0.5 0.25 0.25
7:               BMW, GM F 0.25     0.25    0.5 0.25 0.25
8:                Toyota F 0.25     0.25    0.5 0.25 0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tidyverse solution very similar to Rose's:

#### data:

```
vehicles <- structure(list(x = structure(c(3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L),
            .Label = c("BMW", "BMW,GM", "BMW,Mercedes,Toyota", "Ford,Mercedes", "GM,Ford", "Toyota"),
            class = "factor"),
            y = structure(c(2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
            .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")),
            .Names = c("x","y"), class = "data.frame", 
            row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

#### Code:

```
library(tidyverse)



vehicles %>%
    group_by(y) %>%
    separate_rows(x) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(y,x) %>%
    summarise(vehicle_cnt = n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(y) %>%
    mutate(ratios = 100*vehicle_cnt/sum(vehicle_cnt)) %>%
    select(y,x,ratios) %>%
    spread(x,ratios)
```

#### Output:

```
       y      BMW     Ford       GM Mercedes   Toyota
    <fctr>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
       F 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667 33.33333
       M 28.57143 14.28571 14.28571 14.28571 28.57143
```

I hope this proves useful.